# Ubuntu 22.04 second monitor flickering issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-prime

I am experiencing screen flickering on my second monitor in Ubuntu 22.04. I tried different solutions like reinstalling nvidia-driver and auto install driver also switching to previous versions of nvidia none of them worked. My current nvidia version is `535.113.01` and it seems that it's installed properly, but it still flickers like crazy. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
Laptop Model: HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-df1xxx
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12
Graphic: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
```

Also, I've tested the cable on two different devices and tried Ubuntu live which is working properly. My guess is that it might be a driver issue.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can it be a bad cable ?

Comment: Nope, I've tested the cable on two different devices, also I tried Ubuntu live and it was working properly I guess it's a driver issue

Comment: Please add this information to your question. This is not a forum. Thanks.